# Python try / except does not seem to work with KeyError

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch

Although I've used try/except clauses hundreds of times, I have never seen behavior like this before and I am baffled right now. May I know what am I missing please?

```py
import pandas as pd
import os


season_ep = {}
for season in range(1, 16):
    for ind, row in pd.read_html('https://thetvdb.com/series/curious-george/seasons/official/%d' % season)[0].iterrows():
        season_ep[row['Name']] = row['Unnamed: 0']

errors = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=nas.local,share=media/TV Shows/Curious George", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        try:
            to_print = season_ep[name.split('-')[-1][:-4]]
            print(to_print)
        except KeyError:
            errors.append(os.path.join(dirs, name))

for e in errors:
    print('ERROR: %s' % e)
```

basically, I'm searching for the key `'Old McGeorgie Had a Farm'` in the dictionary `season_ep` which returns a `KeyError`, but I don't understand why I'm receiving the following error. I would expect the `except` part to recognize the `KeyError` and take over, allowing the code to execute fully.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jthom/PycharmProjects/TVDB_ID/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    to_print = season_ep[name.split('-')[-1][:-4]]
KeyError: 'Old McGeorgie Had a Farm'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/278/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/278/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/jthom/PycharmProjects/TVDB_ID/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    errors.append(os.path.join(dirs, name))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/posixpath.py", line 76, in join
    a = os.fspath(a)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

I'm running Python 3.10.4 on Ubuntu 22.04. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The error is caused by the code in the except block, the KeyError is being caught just fine

Comment: `dirs` is a list and `os.path.join` wants a string or bytes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look carefully at the stack trace you will see this snippet: `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred`. This is telling you that the above `KeyError` was caught, but another exception was raised in the `execpt` block.

The simplest way to get around this would be to add a nested `try-except`:

```py
        try:
            to_print = season_ep[name.split('-')[-1][:-4]]
            print(to_print)
        except KeyError:
            try:
                errors.append(os.path.join(dirs, name))
            except TypeError:
                # handle this error somehow
                pass
```

The root of your issue here is that you are passing a list to [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) expecting a `str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list`. My guess is you want to join the `root` value rather than `dirs`. You can see something similar in an example for the docs for [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

```py
# Delete everything reachable from the directory named in "top",
# assuming there are no symbolic links.
# CAUTION:  This is dangerous!  For example, if top == '/', it
# could delete all your disk files.
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        os.remove(os.path.join(root, name))
    for name in dirs:
        os.rmdir(os.path.join(root, name))
```

All in all your path joining code should look like this:

```py
                errors.append(os.path.join(root, name))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! That makes a lot of sense, I was thrown off by the KeyError that was reported first.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to collect a list of error locations, you only need to append the path name `root` and filename `name`

```
    try:
        to_print = season_ep[name.split('-')[-1][:-4]]
        print(to_print)
    except KeyError:
        #errors.append(os.path.join(dirs, name))
        errors.append(os.path.join(root, name))
```